# Clean URL not working on foreign language

Tags: uri

I have migrated a drupal 7's website from current hosting to another new hosting. However, after the migration all seems well except the content with the foreign URL showed error. e.g

http://newDomain.com/article/新-ipad-可能会发布

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

but in the original website there's no such problem. I can access the page without problem.

http://oldDomain.com/article/新-ipad-可能会发布

I tried to disable the clean URL on the new hosting, the page displays the content correctly. e.g

http://newDomain.com/?q=article/新-ipad-可能会发布

But once the clean URL enabled, the "Bad Request" error showed again. Wondering how to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Is `utf8-url-support-enabled` activated on the new server?

Comment: how to check this? where to enable it ?